# When data found recieve 'str' object is not callable error

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a very strange error when using Django Rest Framework. When ever I use the RetrieveAPIView and the data is found I get a error, when data is not found I get the normal window showing the JSON of

```
{
"detail": "Not found."
}
```

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

from items.views import ItemRetrieveView


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^api/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ItemRetrieveView.as_view()),

]
```

seriliazers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Item

class ItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('pk','name','desc','created')
```

view.py- When I change RetrieveAPIViews to RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView I always get 'str' object is not callable even when data does not exist.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from rest_framework import generics

from .models import Item
from .serializers import ItemSerializer

class ItemRetrieveView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):

    lookup_field = 'pk'
    queryset = Item.objects.all()
    serializer_class = 'ItemSerializer'
```

model.py

```
from django.db import models

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add = True)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length = 30)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.name)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
serializer_class = 'ItemSerializer'
```

replace `'ItemSerializer'` with `ItemSerializer`, class is expected other than string

> serializer_class - The serializer class that should be used for validating and deserializing input, and for serializing output. Typically, you must either set this attribute, or override the get_serializer_class() method.
>
> get_serializer_class(self)
>   Returns the class that should be used for the serializer. Defaults to returning the serializer_class attribute.

You can either returns class `ItemSerializer` or *override* `get_serializer_class(self)` like:

```
def get_serializer_class(self):
    return ItemSerializer
```

Answer (score 2):

You are assigning string value to serializer_class. In your code change

```
serializer_class = 'ItemSerializer'
```

to

```
serializer_class = ItemSerializer
```